# Assigning a variable in one dataset to multiple fields in another dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I'm trying to assign a variable in one dataframe into multiple rows of another dataframe - namely the AWND variable here (average wind speed).

I'm trying to obtain the AWND from 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz5hh.png)

And I am trying to match it with multiple dates based on the date
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCXne.png)

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
dfNew <- merge(dfWeather, dfFlight, by="DATE")
```

I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

Should I do a join?

(EDIT: Here's the data- https://shrib.com/#-7dXevTkb12Bt6Kdfxim  (this is the dput output of the data I am getting AWND from)

I got the flights data (that I am trying to match dates with) from the nycflights13 package, and then I subset the `flights` data to include only the carriers that had at least 1000 flights depart from LaGuardia.

Comment: Please share the data via `dput`

Comment: edited above - and included the dput of the data I am calling AWND from, as well as the description of the data I got the flights data from as the dput was too big to show.

Comment: Still not very clear on what exactly  you need

Comment: It sounds like you do need a join, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

The `flights` data has the date-time class as shown in your tibble. First, make sure that the elements you want to join between are the same i.e. `2013-01-01 05:00:00` will not match with `2013-01-01` in your `dfWeather` data.frame

```
# Make sure dates match between data.frames
dfFlight$DATE <- stringr::str_extract(dfFlight$DATE, "\\S*")

# Join AWND wherever dates match to left-hand side
dfNew <- dplyr::left_join(dfFlight, dfWeather, by = "DATE")
```

I did assume some things about your data since I couldn't fully see what you're working with from screenshot. This is my first answer on Stack Overflow, so feel free to edit or leave me suggestions

Comment: Thanks! This really helped!